# Node express console.log(req.body) is empty in post request

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, post

Express and I'm trying to build a registration form. For testing purposes I want to display my data from the fields of form to my console. But I'm not getting any kind of data in the req.body parameters. Below is my server.js file code. I don't know where I am wrong

[image: result]

As you can see in the image that curly braces are empty

Server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
//bringing pool object from dbConfig file
const { pool } = require('./dbConfig');


const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

/*importing ejs middleware to tell app to render 
ejs files according to the routes defined below*/
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

//middleware for sending details from frontend to the server {body-parser}
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

//register post request
app.post('/users/register', (req, res) => {
console.log(req.body);
res.send('heelo');

});
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Please show how you are sending the request.

Answer (score 0):

try adding [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) and also check you request maybe the body is empty.

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
//bringing pool object from dbConfig file
// const { pool } = require("./dbConfig");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

/*importing ejs middleware to tell app to render 
ejs files according to the routes defined below*/
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

//middleware for sending details from frontend to the server {body-parser}
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use(bodyParser.json());

//register post request
app.post("/users/register", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.send("heelo");
});

app.listen(port, (err) => {
  if (err) console.error(err);
  else console.log(`server running on port ${port}`);
});
```

Comment: I have checked with the body-parser as well although I think they have included body-parser ad default in express now. Anyhow it didn't work even by adding it separately. And how do I check the request in another way?

Comment: after i added the body-parser in your code its working. here's the curl request using postman 

`curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:3000/users/register' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
 "mssg": "foo"
}'`